# discord.js Discord bot returns "TypeError: cmd.run is not a function"

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

The code is:

```
module.exports = (client, message) => {
if (message.author.bot) return;

if (message.content.indexOf(client.config.prefix) !== 0) return;

const args = message.content.slice(client.config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

const cmd = client.commands.get(command);

if (!cmd) return;

cmd.run(client, message, args);
};
```

and the Error message is:

```
cmd.run(client, message, args);
    ^
TypeError: cmd.run is not a function
```

What can I use instead of run, or how I can fix the problem?

Comment: You have to show us the command file you're trying to execute. Odds are, the object it's exporting does not have a `run` property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, because `client.commands` doesn't exist in any version of discord.js that I used, so you may look at this part of your code.

(Maybe we can help you a bit more if you give us a bigger part of the code, which may give us informations about variables, or maybe give more informations about what you're trying to do.)
Thanks ;)

Comment: `client.commands` is commonly added by the user to handle commands. See [Discord.js Guide - Command Handling](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#dynamically-reading-command-files)